# Concatenate multiple columns - formula issue with two columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, concatenation

Am trying to merge four columns of numbers with hyphens between; have done it before, but this time as soon as i get to the third column (S2) the formula turns purple as if there is an error.  have read all sorts of posts about formatting as general not text, have tried all permutations of commas, ampersands, spaces - just don't see the problem. what am i missing? elsewhere in my s/sheet the concatenate function works, but always only two columns involved.

Column data is simple such as:
1  0  2  4

`=CONCATENATE(Q2&"-"&R2,S2,T2)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following it is the same formula
`=Concatenate(Q2,"-",R2,S2,T2)`
and the formatting should be General